# Why is it necessary to join on multiple columns SQL?

Tags: sql

In a general sense in SQL joins, what is the benefit to joining tables with multiple versus one column?

Comment: You would do this when the data model is set up to use multiple columns for keys.  The benefit is getting accurate results from your queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the structure of your data. One column may not be enough to properly identify matching rows.

Consider joining on `Address` data (as an example). If you only join on the `Address` line, but not `City/State`, you might have rows match to both

```
123 Front St, New York City, NY
```

and

```
123 Front St, Los Angeles, CA
```

even though your person only lives in one place.

side note: joining on address lines probably means your database needs normalizing. I use it as an example only

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make a small example.   It really helped me understand.  I know this is basic stuff but not understanding basic stuff feels the same as not understanding advanced stuff.